# Understanding the benefit of naming a returned object in the module pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, module-pattern

I understand stylistically why you would name a returned object, for organization etc. However, I don't understand the benefit of adding or removing methods or the ability to update properties at runtime.

```
var foo = (function(){
    var publicAPI = {
        bar: function(){
            publicAPI.baz();
        },
        baz: function(){
            console.log("baz");
        }
    };
    return publicAPI;
})();
```

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear. As far as I can tell, you're asking why you'd use `pubicAPI` in the second example, but given that the two examples are different in several *other* ways...?

Comment: Research "Revealing Module Pattern"

Comment: @ T.J. Chowder - Think you're right—I'll update it. Now that I've thought about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the public api will have access to a variable inside of the closure and will be the exclusive way to access the value(s).

You example above is superfluous since the api can only access the object returned, but if you add another variable that only publicAPI can access, then you have created privacy.

```
var foo = (function(){
    //private 
    var _foo = {name: 'Foo'};
    var publicAPI = {
        getName: function(){
            return _foo.name;
        },
        setName: function(name){
            _foo.name = name;
        },
    };
    return publicAPI;
})();
```

Comment: So the `_foo` object would act as the repository for all our data or even other private functions?

Comment: In the example above, you would only have access to the name property of  _foo.    It is completely up to you how you use the privacy.  Typically, this pattern is used when you have values that you want to limit access to to prevent people from accidentally stepping on something. You would need to add a method to publicAPI if you wanted to add other properties to _foo.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is to get better call stack when there is an error.
For example, if you change `console.log` to `console.blog` then you'll get error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: console.blog is not a function(…)
publicAPI.baz @ VM167:8
(anonymous function) @ VM241:2
...
```

Here you immediately see that the problem is in the `publicAPI.baz`.